# a4j Render not working

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a modal panel similar to the one below in the xhtml page.

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:commandLink action="" rerender="panel1">
</h:form>

<a4j:outputPanel id="panel1">
    <rich:modalpanel>
        <a4j:form>
            <h:panelgroup binding=#{mybean.panel}/>
                <a4j:commandButton id="save">
        </a4j:form>
    </rich:modalpanel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

When I click on the a4j command link,want to display the modal panel with differrent values. It works correctly if there is no a4j:form inside the modal panel. But I want to validate and save the attributes inside the modal panel on click of save button, and hence couldnt proceed with out the form component. But strangely when I add the a4j:form, panel group stop re rendering values. Please help me to sove this.

I also tried to place both inside same form, but then it worked in a very irregular manner.

Comment: Try using `<h:form>` instead of `<a4j:form>`. Also, make sure your managed bean has session scope or is a request scope with `@KeepAlive` annotation in the managed bean class declaration.

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza - I tried that now. But still not working. When I put a normal input text its working correctly, but this panel group is not getting re rendered. This panel group is created dynamically using a bind attribute, is that what causing this behavior ?

Comment: Which JSF version are you working with, 1.2 or 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it this way:

```
<h:form>
<a4j:commandLink action="" rerender="panel1">
</h:form>



<rich:modalpanel>
  <h:form>
     <a4j:outputPanel id="panel1">
     <h:panelgroup binding=#{mybean.panel}/>
     <a4j:commandButton id="save">
     </a4j:outputPanel>
  </h:form>
</rich:modalpanel>
```

Works for me with Popuppanel

Comment: Also a4j:commandLink tag ha no rerender attribute just render

Comment: @enricko in RichFaces 3, there is `reRender`. From RichFaces 4, this is renamed to `render`.

Comment: you must  work with richfaces3? maybe you could switch to 4 and try it with popup panel if 3 is not a must

Comment: Changing the version of richfaces can be done only as a last resort. Is there no way this going to work?